# How can I delete customers that never logged in?

Tags: magento2, customer

I want to clean up my customers. How can I delete customer accounts that have never been logged in to?

Comment: Please add more information regarding what have you tried so far?

Comment: what do you mean of "never logged in"?

Comment: i don't have a clue how I must do this. i Search all over the web with no result.

Comment: I want to remove clients who have never logged in. There is a status in Magento : Last Logged In: Never (Offline)

Comment: accept the answer If you find it helpful , so it helps other community members @MaartenV1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script for you :), just create a new PHP file in your Magento 2 root directory and paste below code and run this script like [http:://YOUR_BASE_URL/YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.php](http://http:://YOUR_BASE_URL/YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.php)

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
$allCustommerIds = $customerCollection->getAllIds();

$resources = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resources->getConnection();
$loginTable = $resources->getTableName('customer_log');
$sql = "Select customer_id FROM " . $loginTable;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $loginIds[] = $item['customer_id'];
}

$neverLoginIds= array_diff($allCustommerIds, $loginIds);
print_r($neverLoginIds);
```

In `$neverLoginIds` you get the only those customer Ids who never login in your webshop.

So, I think from customer Ids you can easily delete the customer.

### Note: Before deleting any customer please cross check with the customer details.

Comment: Array ( [1] => 119992 ) is the result...and now?

Comment: Now load this customer id and delete that customer by script it's simple @MaartenV1

Comment: I think this script solved your problem so you should accept it answer. you can accept the answer by tick marking this answer @MaartenV1

Comment: "by tick marking this answer" where can I do that?

Comment: near the answer you can find right symbol @MaartenV1 :)